# Java Web Service Exception - NullPointException

Tags: java, xml

I am a Beginner in Java and I am trying to build a Web Service that needs to read Data from XML file. I am using this example XML:

`<message>Customer Name</message>`

This is my Web Method to read the inner XML text:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "ProcessMessage")
public void ProcessMessage(@WebParam(name = "name") String strXML){
    String strMessage="";
    try {
        String xmlString = strXML;
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
        JAXBElement<String> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSource, String.class);
        strMessage =  je.getValue();
        Response response = Response.status(200).build();
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(service.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

When I run Web Service, input XML example from above and click the button it throws an Exception:

`WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message : null;`

What is wrong with my Web Method?

Comment: try printing stacktrace in catch block and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tyr to change your method's `public void` to `public string` and return some string at the end of the function. For example, try to return your `strMessage` at the end.